# How to pass environment variable to devcontainer at start-up

Tags: vscode-devcontainer

I want to use my *devcontainer* for CI/CD on *Jenkins*. *Jenkins* can setup *ssh-agent*, so I can use it inside the container. Therefore I need to pass the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` into the container when it is started.
I hoped I could do something like this:

`devcontainer up --workspace-folder . --mount "type=bind,source=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,target=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" --remote-env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

But unfortunately that doesn't work. How can I change the environment at start-up?